# Are galaxies merely groups of nearby stars that collected together, or do the stars share a common birth?

Tags: astrophysics, dark-matter, galaxies, structure-formation, galaxy-clusters

The [news](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature25767) that some galaxies have dark matter and others do not leads to the question of how this could be possible. If galaxies are merely groups of stars that gathered together (under gravitational pull) leaving space in-between, then would not the randomly spread dark matter also have been pulled into the galaxy?  Or does a galaxy have a central birth such that some contain dark matter and others do not?

Comment: The news I heard is 1 galaxy has been found to not contain dark matter. I don't think one should be convinced that now we are in a "some do", "some don't" scenario where it's equally likely a galaxy has or doesn't have DM. It very well could be that galaxies without DM are anomalies and they could have formed in a different mechanism from the way most galaxies are formed. I haven't read much into it though, just saw some headlines.

Comment: The present model of the history of the universe  https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Planck/History_of_cosmic_structure_formation gives a focus for the creation of the galaxies, dependent on the explanation of the small anisotropies of cosmic microwave background. The hypothesis is that the anisotropies at that early time congealed to the matter that became clusters of galaxies, galaxies and stars. The model is still being worked out, if, as you say there is different need of dark matter, the model has to expand to include that observation .

Comment: Dark matter haloes formed first and baryonic matter (i.e. star stuff) fell into the gravitational wells of the DM, eventually virialising into stars and galaxies. There is no reason in this picture why a galaxy couldn't form without DM, as baryonic matter has the same gravitational behaviour.

Comment: The [article](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature25767) that made those headlines is titled "A galaxy lacking dark matter". Actually reading the article reveals that the title should be interpreted as "it has less than expected" and not "it has none at all". The authors were being deliberately provocative with the title (as stated on the [blog](https://www.pietervandokkum.com/ngc1052-df2) of the lead author).